# Can I install robotframework 3.0.2rc1 version with python 2.7.13

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework, selenium2library

I want to use RIDE to create automation test cases for browser based applications. I looked all over internet for installation instructions and found many. But none of them clearly call out which combination of `robotframework` and `Python` version should I use.

Please let me know if I can use below:
decorator=4.0.11  docutils=0.13.1  pygments=2.2.0  robotframework=3.0.2rc1  robotframework-ride=1.5.2.1  robotframework-selenium2library=1.8.0 and   selenium==3.0.2

wxPython version will be wxPython2.8-win32-unicode-2.8.12.1-py27.exe. I am on windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes @Goralight. I couldnt use 'pip' or 'easy_install' so installed it through source code by using command 'python setup.py install' for each of them. But then RIDE didnt recognize the selenium2library at all. Import was always successful so I am not sure what the issue is. That is why I wanted to know if the combination that I am using is valid or not.

Comment: can you please check the spelling given for library, it should be `Selenium2Library`